# New member gets vendetta down-votes from well established member

Tags: support

I know who it is and I can watch my numbers fall within seconds of one another.  Help me!  LOL  I have (11) points.  Count them, 11!  The systems tells me I'm getting close to forever banishment.

Update:  As a result of asking the above question, I've now lost both badges.  LOL  I don't even know how you lose those!  Well, well, well.  My very own personal troll surely must feel the power.

Updated update:  Who has the power to completely clean my account of all activity?  Ever been on the receiving end of a narcissistic rage?  LOL  I know I have.

Comment: I feel for you. But: Don't be paranoid. How can you possibly have any idea who might be downvoting? And how do you know it is a vendetta rather than an objective account of quality? There's only been 4 downvotes...that is not a lot (for a newcomer). Anyway, good to come here, a mod should be able to address if there's really something weird going on.

Comment: Re: update and updated update, you didn't lose any badges or activity or anything. You're on meta now, this grayish place. Your profile here is separate from your profile on the main site, the chamois place. It can take some time to get accustomed to how this all works, and I can only suggest that you take just that time to get accustomed. You might even find out that your claim about being downvoted by a particular user is similarly unsubstantiated as the one about losing badges. Even for myself as a mod, it is impossible to know who downvotes me when and why. For the rest, see Kit's answer.

Comment: Unjust down votes are nasty. Many of us have had serial down voters and know how it feels. But, because of this meta post, I just looked at your answers (like Mitch, I saw answers without down votes), some of which are far from what answers are supposed to be on **any** SE site. [One was sarcastic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197598/) and one showed a [knowing disregard for site guidelines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181132/). It's bad form to post in meta for protection while flaunting bad attitudes on the main site.

Answer (score 8):

I took a look at your account, and there's no enough activity at this point to draw any conclusions. Please do let us know if you continue having trouble. You can do this by flagging one of your downvoted posts with an "other" flag and leave a little note for the moderators asking us to look into serial downvoting.

I noticed when I was surveying your answers that you are generally not answering the question. This site is not a forum; when you post an answer, we expect it to answer the question. You'll have the privilege to leave comments when you get to 50 rep points. You can use comments to ask for clarification or provide feedback to another poster, which it what it seems like you are using the answer section for. That might account for the downvotes you've noted.

I can tell by your posts that you are interested in the site. I hope this early experience doesn't discourage you from exploring here more. Take a look at some of the highly-upvoted answers and that will give you an idea of what we're looking for here.